# Sharing types in a modular application architecture

Tags: architecture, modularity, n-tier-architecture

I have an application under development that is following a modular application design.  There is a 'core' vertical stack that provides common, central services such as authentication/authorization, logging, data access, etc.  Context-specific areas are implemented in modules that reference the core assembly in the same logical layer.

The application is a service app with a facade layer, domain layer and infrastructure code containing the data access code.  Each module will implement a domain layer assembly.  If the module has a public API, it will also implement a facade assembly.

For example, the solution contains:

Core.Api  - Facade assembly for the core API

Core      - Domain assembly for the core services, entities, etc.

Core.Data - Core data access assembly

ModuleA.Api - Facade assembly for module A (references Core.Api)

ModuleA     - Domain assembly for module A (references Core)

ModuleB.Api - Facade assembly for module B (references Core.Api)

ModuleB     - Domain assembly for module B (references Core)

[image]

(and so on. We'll have about 24 modules when done.)

All of this is bound together using DI with Unity as the IoC container. The WebHost project defines the configuration where the various implementations are mapped to the interfaces they fullfill.

This approach is not simply for logical purposes but to allow us flexibility in implementation (i.e. we can change the implementation of a module without breaking or even touching the other code). It also makes it extremely ease to divide work across teams and to extend the application with new modules with little risk of regression error in other code.

My question is what to do when ModuleB requires one or more types defined in ModuleA?  Is it acceptable for ModuleB to reference ModuleA or do I need to move ModuleA into Core?

**UPDATE**

In looking at implementing some of the changes discussed below I ran into a gotcha that leads me to this clarification...

There are two places where my modules are inter-dependent. Following the approach discussed below, I can move the interfaces and types I want shared from Module1 to Core which allows ModuleB to make use of them without tightly coupling ModuleA and ModuleB. However, I also need to use some of the data contracts defined in ModuleA.Api for the service operations in ModuleB.Api. This makes me question the design.

Because of IP, I can't describe our exact use-case but suffice it to say that ModuleA has an EntityA domain object.  ModuleA.Api defines the EntityContractA data contract (DTO) that is exposed by the public API.  ModuleB.Api has a method that requires EntityContractA as a parameter then delegates to a method in ModuleB that accepts EntityA as a parameter.

Again, moving EntityA into Core solves the domain layer problem but doesn't help me with the facade layer. Moving EntityContractA into Core.Api makes the whole thing smell a bit.

Here's an example what I need to accomplish:

In ModuleB.Api.ServiceFacadeB:

```
public EntityContractB FilterBy(EntityContractA contractA)
{
    var entityA = Mapper.Map<EntityContractA, EntityA>(contractA);

    var entityB = domainService.FilterBy(entityA);

    var contractB = Mapper.Map<EntityB, EntityContractB>(entityB);

    return contractB;
}
```

where domainService is ModuleA.ServiceB:

```
public EntityB FilterBy(EntityA entityA)
{
    // Do work
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The good news: what you describe is actually a good architecture with clear seperation of concerns and modularity patterns. It allows your teams to develop modules independent from each other and only have dependencies on each others interfaces (facade / API). This is a best practice!

The (potential) bad news: If you would start by directly referencing Module1 from Module2, you will single-handedly break this beautiful architecture. The team creating Module1 only needed to care about keeping their interface stable, but because of the direct reference now also need to be careful with changing their implementation.

My suggestion: If you need a type in Module2 that is now defined in Module1, make sure you move it into the Core API or the Module1 API classes. This formalizes the fact that your assembly is depending on those types and makes it clear they need to be kept stable.

Comment: How would you approach moving them into Core. Would you define just the interfaces and the types used by them and leave the implementation in the module?

Comment: I think (but not sure) that the current architecture conceptually requires the implementation to be in the same namespace as the interface. That would mean that you have to move it completely from Module1 to Core.

Comment: I don't think there's such a constraint when using an IoC container.  I already have all of my 'services' implementing interfaces. The more I think about it, the more sense it makes to only put the 'contract' (interface) and supporting types in Core and leave the implementation in a separate Module. This will ensure that both modules only need to reference Core but allow us to still have the benefit of modularity with the implementation.

Comment: But (there is always a but :-)) this will make your Core a global market place for all your modules and it will expose all capabilities of all modules your solution has. I was more impressed by the API facades for each Module. That is something I would like to keep ...

Comment: I agree but at the same time, I need to support shared services. The only way I can think to accomplish this is to put the interfaces and types in a common location. I suppose I could limit this to just the types (domain object) and not the service interfaces unless those services require sharing (which I suspect will occur less than sharing the types). If you have another idea, I'm all ears...

Comment: After having read your update, I would like to propose to move the common datacontracts into Core.API. The data contact can then be used for all APIs and all modules.

Comment: After a bit more review, I think this is the best way to go.  These types are actually more aptly defined as Value Types than Entities or Aggregates (in DDD parlance). Looking at it this way makes treating them this way feel more natural.

Answer (score 0):

Module2 need to have reference of Module1. interdependence between modules doesn't make a case for moving pieces to common core code.

Comment: All of the guidelines I've read say otherwise which is why I hesitated to do so. Kroonwijk makes a good point about the effect changes to Module1 will have on any other modules with direct references. By moving the interfaces and supporting types into Core, I allow other modules to make use of the code but leave the implementation decoupled so changes don't require recompilation and deployment of them all, for instance.

Comment: will it be possible to explain bit about your app, and modules that you are considering here. I would like to understand your app because most of time these design decisions are subjected to application use case.

Comment: Not sure I can go into much more detail than I have because of IP. Is there something specific you'd like to know?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it acceptable for ModuleB to reference ModuleA or do I need to move
>   ModuleA into Core?

No, I'd redefine shared types somewhere that wasn't ties to a specific module.  Just make sure that wherever you define these shared types is free of dependencies.

[Warning, self promotion:] In the [5-Layer Architecture](http://morphological.wordpress.com/2011/08/29/5-layer-architecture/) view of the world, they'd go in the "Common" layer.

Comment: I appreciate the link and will have to read it more thoroughly when I have more time.  Interesting assertions, although it seems like you take more of a data-centric approach whereas OO suggests modeling based on behavior (thus no POCOs). Not sure that makes any difference here, though.  I'm leaning towards moving the abstractions (interfaces) and supporting types into my Core libraries (which are my Common layer following your terminology). My only fear is that I don't want this to become rampant which defeats the purpose of a modular architecture.